# Hide 3 Bottom Buttons (Back/Home/Recent) (Android full screen)

Tags: android, .net, maui

I am developing an app for price verification on an Android device (OS version 7.1.2, API Level 25) using .NET MAUI RC3.

I have managed to make the status bar at the top disappear, as well as the .NET MAUI navigation bar, using Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False", however, I'm stuck at trying to disable the Android navigation bar at the bottom:

[image: What I want to hide...]

I have tried:

- NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" in the
- NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" in the
- NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" in the

I have set this in the MainActivity, but it only removes the status bar at the top:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.Window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
    }
}
```

The examples I found for hiding the navigation buttons all fail with syntax errors for various reasons:

- DecorView doesn't have the SetSystemUiVisibility method
- Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags doesn't have all the flags, such as "immersive", etc.
- WindowInsetsController is not available in API version 25

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Joerg.

Comment: Have you experimented with different Minimum and Target API versions? The mechanisms you mention are from various API levels; I would have expected that some combination would work. BUT perhaps Android 11 and/or 12 are too different from the original SetSystemUIVisibility version (KitKat?) ... If you specify minimum API 30, then is WindowInsetsController there?

Comment: Hello @ToolmakerSteve. I have set the `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25"
          android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>` since that's the API level I am currently specifically building for. However, I do have a warning in VS2022 that the "targetFrameworkVersion" is higher than the targetSdkVersion, and that ACW-31 will be used for that reason, but I have not a way to set a specific targetFrameworkVersion (tried in .csproj with no success). The reason WindowInsetsController will not work is my devices are a lower version, and other ways maybe don't work because the compiler isn't offering them.

Comment: Here's the specific warning I am getting in VS2022: `Warning XA4211 AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '25' is less than $(TargetFrameworkVersion) ''. Using API-31 for ACW compilation.` All searches for this messages refer to VS2019 or earlier and the solutions indicated there do not apply to VS2022...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MainActivity.cs:

```cs
using Android.Views;
...
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
            (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
             SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
    }
}
```

I don't know which of those flags are needed, so I set them all.

Tested on a newer device. But should work fine on an API-25 device.

`SystemUiVisibility` is marked as deprecated, but it still works.
If you set targetSdkVersion to API-31, you could add if-test to use WindowInsetsController where available. (Though it sounds like you have a specific device to run on, so not relevant to your situation.)

NOTE: targetSdkVersion and TargetFrameworkVersion do not have to be API-25; its fine if they are newer. Not sure how Maui is setting TargetFrameworkVersion. I think `net6.0-android` is defaulting to API-31. Causing the warning you see.