# MAUI: Hide and show bottom options (Back/Home/Recent) and view page in full screen

Tags: maui

I want to hide the bottom options (Back/Home/Recent) for a particular page in my MAUI application. I implemented it as per the solution on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72266421/hide-3-bottom-buttons-back-home-recent-android-full-screen).

**On the Constructor of the page**

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new HideBottomOptions("hide"));
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<HideBottomOptions>(this, (r, m) =>
        {
            if (m.Value == "hide")
            {
                this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
                (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                 SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I leave that page I am sending `WeakReferenceMessenger` from `OnDisappearing` section like below:

```
protected override void ondisappearing()
{
    base.ondisappearing();
    weakreferencemessenger.default.send(new hidebottomoptions("show"));
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<HideBottomOptions>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    if (m.Value == "show")
    {
        this.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
        (SystemUiFlags.Visible | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
         SystemUiFlags.Visible | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
    }
});
```

But I am getting below exception when I added the above section. I need to show the bottom bar options when I leave that particular page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the WeakReferenceMessenger. You can use the conditional compilation instead of it.

```
#if  ANDROID
using Android.Views;
#endif
  ...
  protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
#if  ANDROID
        Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
                (SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation |
                 SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
#endif
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
#if  ANDROID
        Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)
        (SystemUiFlags.Visible |
         SystemUiFlags.Visible | SystemUiFlags.Immersive);
#endif
    }
```

In additio, the systemuivisibility was deprecated, you can use  `Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.InsetsController.Hide( WindowInsets.Type.SystemBars());` to hide the system bars and use the  `Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.InsetsController.Show( WindowInsets.Type.SystemBars() );` to show them.

Comment: We can hide the bottom options with this, but if we swipe on bottom the options are appearing. So is there a way to hide the bottom options permanently or disable its tap?

Comment: There is no way can do that. User swipes on the bottom means he want exit the fullscreen. @MatthewPans

Comment: At least disable when tapping? I disabled the back arrow tap, but any way to disable the home and latest?

Comment: No, that makes your app seems like a hacker. There is no api can do that.  @MatthewPans

Comment: No that is our feature, for leaving the page the user need to do some extra secret activities.